# Codeigniter pagination using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I am using ajax pagination using codeigniter

```
<script>
$("div.review_pagination a").click(function(){
    var reviews_url=$(this).attr("href");
    alert(reviews_url);
    readmore_after5(); 
    $.post( reviews_url,{product_id:<?php echo $product->id;?> }
        ,function( data ){

     $('#review_pagination').html(data);   
    },"html");

    return false;
 });   

    });
</script>
```

here my view page

```
<div class="span12" id="review_pagination">
        <!-- load the ajax call-->

        <?php echo $this->load->view('reviews_list');?>

          </div>

 $data['reviews']= $this->Product_model->get_reviews($id,$limit,$start);
 $data['total']= $this->Product_model->get_reviews_count($id,$term);
```

Below is the pagination,issue with the pagination not only '2', if i go like 2,3,4,5,6 data is coming but pagination active is not changing from 1 to 2,3,4,5,6 so based on the data loading

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

  $config['base_url'] = base_url().'myaccount/ajax_reviews_data';
  $config['total_rows']     = $data['total'];
  $config['per_page']       = $rows;
  $config['uri_segment']        = 5;
  $config['first_link']     = 'First';
  $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
  $config['first_tag_close']    = '</li>';
  $config['last_link']      = 'Last';
  $config['last_tag_open']  = '<li>';
  $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
  $config['prev_link']                = '&lt;';
  $config['full_tag_open']  = '<div class="pagination review_pagination"><ul>';
  $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
  $config['cur_tag_open']       = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
  $config['cur_tag_close']  = '</a></li>';
  $config['prev_link']                = '&lt;';
  $config['prev_tag_open']        = '<li>';
  $config['prev_tag_close']        = '</li>';
  $config['num_tag_open']       = '<li>';
  $config['num_tag_close']  = '</li>';
  $this->pagination->initialize($config);
  //$data['video_reviews']= $this->Product_model->get_video_reviews($id);
  if(isset($_GET['v'])&&$_GET['v']==1)
      $data['show_video_review']=1;
  else   
     $data['show_video_review']=0;

$this->template->write_view('content', 'product',$data, TRUE);
$this->template->render();
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Page no. 2 is not having class "Active"?

Comment: not only '2', if i go like 2,3,4,5,6 data is coming but pagination active is not changing from 1 to 2,3,4,5,6 so based on the data loading

Comment: Pagination is working but active class not applied. Right?

Comment: yes that is the problem, pls see my implementation here dev.trynbuyindia.com//close-up-flow-wrap

Comment: check your css. it may override the your active style.

Comment: How to overide the css.I posted one link above, can u pls see that and give exact solution for me.

Comment: i given the link for you above can u pls check the problem with the active class of pagination

Comment: pls see my implementation here dev.trynbuyindia.com//close-up-flow-wrap

Comment: set $config['uri_segment']        = 3; and then try

Comment: yeah, i tried it it is not working. that url is a slug if 'close-up-flow-wrap' means cart/product/29

Comment: got he solition by adding var parentPages = $(this).parent();
     console.log(parentPages);
     $(parentPages).siblings().removeClass('active');
     $(parentPages).addClass('active');

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell everything from the code you posted, but remember that the pagination links are the output of the pagination library, while your results are the output of your model (+ formatting in your html)

It sounds to me like you are returning the results in your ajax response, but not the new pagination library output.

When you sort that out, you should take your code to the CI forums for a code review, because you seem to be making a lot of mistakes in how you are arranging your code that people can help you with, but is too long for this thread to go into